# Press Home button in Appium Java client

Tags: java, appium

I am new to appium. It might be a silly question. Wanted to know how will i click home button using java bindings.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well if you want to send an app in background then simply use `driver.CloseApp()` function and relaunch it by `driver.OpenApp()`

You can also use press keycode method 
Below are the codes

```
Home Menu Button - 82
Back Button - 4
Recent app - 187
```

Answer (score 6):

Appium has since deprecated `pressKeyCode`. Instead, use:

`driver.pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.HOME));`

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean applicationClose(String packageName) {
        appiumDriver.closeApp();
        return true;
    }

or
String ud_id=  ;
String str = "adb -s ud_id shell keyevent KEYCODE_HOME";
        String line;
        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandStr);
            InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                str += line;

            System.out.println("Command output: " + str);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ReportAppium.getSnapShot(appiumDriver, "run:" + commandStr);
        return str;
```

Answer (score 0):

please try below code

```
driver.pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.HOME);` // it will android device home` button
```

if you want to perform any other operation with android device keys you can use same approach.You will get keys in AndroidKeyCode.

hope these helps you.

Answer (score 0):

For Android :

```
driver.pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.HOME);
```

For IOS:

```
driver.executeScript("mobile: pressButton", ImmutableMap.of("name", "home"));
```

Comment: PressKeyCode is now deprecated

Answer (score 0):

`closeApp()` for me - its force stop of app. If u dont need it u can use:

`driver.runAppInBackground(Duration.ofSeconds(x));`

puts the application in the background for a certain time.
Unfortunately this is the only solution that helped me with MIUI.

Answer (score 0):

I am using java client 8.5.0 and below code works fine for me

```
    driver.pressKey(new io.appium.java_client.android.nativekey.KeyEvent(AndroidKey.HOME));
```